# iframe does not load within a css column until page resize

Tags: html, css, iframe

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nbHOSEc9GGXnajPUdA4I?p=preview

I have a 3 column layout full of cards, one of which contains a google maps iframe. When the page loads, the iframe jumps out of order and appears to place itself as if there were no columns until the window is resized, then it jumps back into place.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="columns">
  <div class="box">
    Lorem
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe class="map" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=London%20Road%2C%20Derby%2C%20United%20Kingdom&key=AIzaSyCX5SkCFvE6-pwrAU2Yx58AYlHiXChRe4U"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Lorem
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.columns {
  -webkit-columns: 3;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.map {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**As it appears on loading**
[image]

**After resize**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I have this as css it works fine for me. Replace your code by this, sometimes that will work.

```
-webkit-columns:  3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-columns: 3; /* Firefox */
columns: 3;
```

Comment: fixed those, same problem occurs